# Error in Xamarin-Windows 10 UWP project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal

I have newly setup the project for Windows 10-UWP. 
But it’s giving following error while startup and exiting the debugger. Nothing working.

Can anybody please help me out?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.UpdateBackButton()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.NavigationPageRenderer.OnLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
```

While working on this to resolve, I found the error was  because of following line used in `OnAppearing` page where I was replacing underlying page:

```
(Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

and replacing above line with following works

```
(Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(page));
```

But this doesn't solve my requirements.

Comment: I think you should show the code that is generating the error instead of the error itself

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using ReactiveUI and most of my xaml elements were getting their bindings from the viewmodel except one, a webview.  After I put the webview's source in the viewmodel along with everything else the error went away.  Mind you, this same method of setting the webview in the code behind works fine on my other pages, not sure why this exact page needed the source in the viewmodel but oh well.